# Deleted app '?' icon in Dock

Tags: dock, icon

I deleted an app from the Applications folder. However the original app icon in the Dock is now appearing as a '?'. I am unable to delete this icon from the dock, when I click to get the Options menu, I dont see any sub-items. I am unable to drag this icon into trash as well. Any ideas as to how this can be done?

Running Mojave: 10.14.3

Comment: Did you try restarting the Dock by running `killall dock`.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema, the `killall dock` command will just return `No matching processes belonging to you were found`, you need to use the proper spelling of the target app, e.g.: `killall Dock`

Comment: Yes, I had tried the `killall Dock`, that doesnt fix the issue. After the dock gets relaunched I can still see the '?' icon.

Comment: If you have Xcode installed, you can delete the app target key from the `persistent-apps` in the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` file and then use `killall Dock`, or you can just delete the `com.apple.dock.plist` file followed by `killall Dock`; however, the latter resets the Dock to the macOS installed layout. Which is why removing the target app from the plist file may be more suitable.

Comment: Just left-click hold & drag it out into the desktop. should give you a Remove option. Let go, done.

Comment: @user3439894 I had tried this. When I open the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` in XCode, the `persistent-apps` shows up as empty `(0 items)`.

Comment: I'm running macOS High Sierra, let be boot a macOS Mojave system and see what's what.

Comment: @Tetsujin That doesnt work either. When I drag out and hold, no option appears. As soon as I let go the icon clicks back into its original spot.

Comment: test you're dragging far enough to see the Remove option appear, using any other app [just drag it back to the Dock afterwards & it won't actually remove]

Comment: Works for me in macOS Mojave as it does in macOS High Sierra, so nothing has changed between the two in this regard from what I'm seeing. If the `persistent-apps` array in the `com.apple.dock.plist` file is truly empty then something else is wrong. I'd back it up and use `killall Dock` afterwards using the following compound command in Terminal, e.g.: `mv ~/Library/com.apple.dock.plist ~/Library/com.apple.dock.plist.bak; killall Dock`

Comment: curious.....what app was it ?

Answer (score -2):

Drag the icon off the dock (not into the trash) and hold it for a second until it says "Remove". Then drop the item and it should go away.

[image]

Comment: The OP stated in comments that he has already tried that and its not working. Also under normal circumstances dragging to the Trash should bring up the Remove from Dock command but it obviously hasn't worked for the OP in this instance.